# Limit question using L'Hospital rule

Tags: calculus

Here is the limit I am trying to do

$$ \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^2 + \mathrm{e}^{4x}}{2x- \mathrm{e}^x} $$

Now, here first, I am trying to identify the indeterminate form so that I can use L'Hospital's rule. Numerator tends to $\infty$ as $x \to \infty $. But the denominator tends to $ \infty - \infty$ as $ x \to \infty$. So, indeterminate form would be

$$ \frac{\infty}{\infty - \infty} $$

So, how to approach this problem here ?

Comment: $2x-e^x=2x\left(1-\frac{e^x}{2x}\right)$. Use L'Hospital's rule to determine its limit.

Comment: Use the rule twice (or thrice, if that makes the result clearer).

Comment: Hospital? Doctor?? I think you mean hopital

Comment: @Buraian in India, we use L'Hospital as the spelling of this french mathematician.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The denominator is indeed of the indeterminate form $\infty-\infty$, but simplifying it we get
$$2x-e^x = e^x\left(\frac{2x}{e^x}-1\right)$$
and since
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{2x}{e^x}=0$$
(e.g. by L'Hopital's), we see that the denominator tends to $-\infty$, so you can proceed with L'Hopital's for the original fraction as usual, as it is of the indeterminate form $\frac{\infty}{-\infty}$.

Answer (score 1):

For the denominator, you have to find the limit $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} (2x-\mathrm{e}^x)$. You have noticed that both terms tend to $\infty$, so we need a more nuanced comparison. (The limit of "$\infty-\infty$", so to speak, could be any real number, or $\pm \infty$ e.g. take $(x+k)-x$ to get limit $k$, and $2x-x$ for $\infty$, and $x-2x$ for $-\infty$.)

Recall that

$$ e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\cdots+\frac{x^n}{n!}+\cdots$$

So $$ 2x-e^x=-1+x-\frac{x^2}{2}-\cdots-\frac{x^n}{n!}-\cdots$$

What is the limit of this as $x\to \infty$?